# Detecting REFERRER 301 redirects in AwStats

Tags: http-status-code-301, awstats

About six months ago, I have moved a website to a new domain, and helped migration using 301 redirects into .htaccess of the old domain.

This morning I was looking at AwStats log of the **new domain**, and was surpised to notice that in the "HTTP Status codes"section, 301 redirects score 77% of the whole codes (seems 200 are not tracked here).
So, what is the proper meaning of the 301 code in those stats? Does it mean that 77% of traffic is incoming (referrer) from 301 redirects or?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have found and answer yet, but I will post this for anyone else who stumbles upon this question:

The **Percent** column of the **HTTP Status Codes** section in the AwStats log does not represent a percentage of total traffic to the site in the selected time frame. The percentage only applies to the traffic captured in the **HTTP Status Codes** section.

Comment: Non answer yet. Could you clarify this? I'm still interested in!

Comment: The **HTTP Status Codes** section will report the number of individual status codes returned during the selected **Reported Period** (which is selected using the drop-downs at the top of the page). 
Let's imagine the following scenario:

Comment: We have chosen May 2011 for our Reported Period
Monthly History reports 1,000 hits for the month of May
HTTP Status Codes lists 2 codes: 301 and 404
    301 has 77 hits and 77%
    404 has 33 hits and 33%

The status codes total up to 100, which is only 10% of the total hits.

301 is not 77% of your total traffic, but 77% of the reported status codes.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be the whole traffic? Shouldn't this section track also the "200" status codes?

Comment: I am not sure of the decision by the AWStats team to show percentage as the percentage of errors vs the percentage of all traffic. 
My guess is "200" status codes were omitted since they are reflected in the "Hits" count.